# Where does astroid change its behavior for pylint checks of relative imports?

Tags: python, pylint, astroid

On a Linux environment, I have the following three files in a folder named `utils`:

1. An empty file `__init__.py`
2. A file named `mymain.py` with the following content:

   ```
   from mytool import foo
   ```
3. A file `mytool.py` with the following content:

   ```
   from subprocess import check_output

   def foo():
       print("Hello World")
   ```

Now I create a virtual environment with the following setup:

```
astroid==2.4.2
isort==5.7.0
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3
packaging==20.9
pylint==2.6.0
pyparsing==2.4.7
six==1.15.0
toml==0.10.2
typed-ast==1.4.2
wrapt==1.12.1
```

Then I run the pylint check on that folder

```
pylint utils
```

or

```
pylint --disable=C,R,W utils  # only the error is of interest
```

it should return a score of 10.

When you now upgrade the version of `astroid` to 2.5.0 and run the check again, you get the error:

```
************* Module utils.mymain
utils/mymain.py:2:0: E0401: Unable to import 'mytool' (import-error)
```

Is the changed behavior because of the deprecated importlib methods, as pointed out [HERE](https://astroid.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html#what-s-new-in-astroid-2-5)?

**Interesting fact**

If you remove the unused import statement in the file `mytool.py`, you also get the same import error even with `astroid` version 2.4.2

Why; How can an unused import possibly affect the outcome of a `pylint` check?

Hint: I have two questions.

Comment: This problem is not reproducible.  https://replit.com/@jumpthrowaway/Astroid

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not reproducible, so it's hard to say whether the *astroid* version and the unused import statement are at the heart of the issue, but we can try investigating other avenues in our quest to better understand what's going on here.

---

### In a nutshell

Executing `pylint --disable=C,R,W utils` behaves as if *utils* is imported as a module, causing the **absolute import** `from mytool import foo` to fail.

---

### In detail

I believe you expected *Pylint* to return the perfect score since executing `python3 utils/mymain.py` from the parent folder or `python3 mymain.py` from the *utils* folder work.

Alas, these methods of execution work because `sys.path[0]` is [initialized](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) to the path of the *utils* folder. Thus, the absolute import statement `from mytool import foo` succeeds, as the package *mytool* is found within the paths specified by `sys.path`.

However, when *Pylint* is executed, its `__main__.py` file is treated as the main module and the path of the *utils* folder is no longer included anywhere within `sys.path` and the absolute import fails.

Here are three different approaches that cause `pylint --disable=C,R,W utils` to return the perfect score:

1. Edit the import statement to be relative, i.e. to `from .mytool import foo`. Note that this change warrants you to execute your script [as a module](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m) from the parent folder (e.g. `python3 -m utils.mymain`).
2. Add the *utils* folder to `PYTHONPATH` before executing the script or to `sys.path` before reaching the absolute import statement.

   However, if you do prefer this approach of using an absolute import, I would recommend rearranging the project structure to reflect a well-designed module and importing it properly (e.g. `from <module>.utils.mytool import foo`). Of course, this requires installing the module locally or manipulating the path to support the import.
3. Try running with *Python 2*. This works without any need for changes, due to the [deprecated](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#removed-syntax) behavior of implicit relative imports in *Python 2*.

---

Addressing your questions on the effect of the *astroid* module and the unused import statement on the outcome of a *Pylint* check:

- Since *Pylint* depends on the *astroid* module to work, a bug in the *astroid* module could affect the outcome of a *Pylint* check in unexpected ways, including in the manner you described.
- Since *Pylint* was executed on the entire *utils* folder, the unused import statement in *utils/mytool.py* could appear as a warning, but it shouldn't alter the outcome of a *Pylint* check in the manner you described (unless it triggers some unexpected behavior in a buggy *astroid* version).

Thus, a buggy *astroid* version, with or without an unused import statement, could yield unexpected results. However, as the problem isn't reproducible, it's hard to research what exactly is going on here.

---

An alternative explanation to this cryptic behavior, suggested by [*Pylint*'s official documentation](https://docs.pylint.org/en/1.6.0/run.html#invoking-pylint), is an installed module of the same name as the one tested:

> You should give *Pylint* the name of a *Python* package or module. *Pylint* will not import this package or module, though uses *Python* internals to locate them and as such is subject to the same rules and configuration. You should pay attention to your `PYTHONPATH`, since it is a common error to analyze an installed version of a module instead of the development version.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but you do NEITHER answer WHY the version of astroid affects the outcome of this setup NOR why the import statement has an effect on the outcome. You said yourself: " an unused import statement shouldn't affect the outcome of a Pylint check, nor should the astroid module". But that was exactly my question. You did not answer my question at all.

Comment: Please try reproducing the problem in a fresh virtual environment. I believe that you'll see that neither the _astroid_ version, nor the unused import statement affect the outcome of the _Pylint_ check, which shall fail on both occasions due to the absolute import statement. Then try the approaches I listed and see whether the issue is resolved.

Comment: Yes, I cannot reproduce it anymore. It seems to have been a "messed up" virtualenv. 

But how can a virtualenv get messed up? How to check if a virtualenv is "Ok"?

Comment: It's hard to tell what exactly happened without a reproducible example or access to the problematic virtual environment. As I alluded to in my answer, the culprit could be an installed module called `mytool`. Specifically, it's possible that between the first execution of _Pylint_ (which worked) and the following ones (which failed), you've uninstalled a module called `mytool` with the function `foo`, removing it from the virtual environment and causing the absolute import to no longer work.

Comment: I changed either the version of `astroid` or the import statement. I did not "by chance" uninstall some module between the trials! Something else must have been broken . But what? How to find out??

Comment: I have found a virtualenv where I can reproduce this behavior. WITH the extra import in the file `mytool.py` `pylint` gives a score of 10, WITHOUT the import it gives the error. I did NOT change anything in between. How to find out, what is going on?

Comment: Great! My first priority would be to test whether the absolute import works when executing the script directly (i.e. without _Pylint_) in order to understand which of the two _Pylint_ behaviors is the correct one. As I explained in my answer, I don't expect the absolute import to work, but if it does, I would research why. Only then I would try debugging _Pylint_,  for example by introducing `pdb` into its _\_\_init\_\_.py_ file (e.g. *lib/python3.8/site-packages/pylint/__init__.py* in the virtual environment).

Comment: I have changed the code to import the module absolute (`from utils.mytool import foo`). Now `pylint` works, but running `python utils/mymain.py` gives an ModuleNotFoundError.

Comment: Now I am not sure how to best debug that code. I do not even know where I should set a breakpoint!

Comment: If you want the absolute import statement `from utils.mytool import foo` to work when executing the script from the parent folder, you can execute it as a module, i.e. with `python3 -m utils.mymain`.

Comment: Yes that works. But how can I possibly debug `pylint` to see the real cause of the problems I have?

Comment: As I wrote in the comment above, you can introduce *pdb* (i.e. `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`) into _Pylint_'s *\_\_init\_\_.py* file (e.g. *lib/python3.8/site-packages/pylint/\_\_init\_\_.py* in the virtual environment). However, why can't you simply circumvent this issue, rather then waste your time trying to debug it? In other words, why can't you use the first two approaches listed in my answer?

Comment: Ok, I give up! I noticed something strange with a virtualenv, there IS definitely an error, a bug, which I am not able to investigate further. End of the story!

Comment: Well, I hope that my answer and the ensuing discussion were helpful nonetheless. If you somehow manage to generate a reproducible example, I'd like to play around and debug it on my side, so do share.

Comment: Sure I will. I am actually trying right now.

Comment: Since the problem is indeed non-reproducible, would you consider cancelling your downvote and even upvoting this answer? Of course, this is just a friendly request and it's entirely up to you to. You don't need to reply to this comment and feel free to reject my request if you feel I wasn't helpful and that you gained nothing from the discussion. Thanks anyway - I enjoyed the challenge :-)

Comment: Sure. I am always trying to be a nice person. Thanks for your detailed input.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing import statement

From:

```
from mytool import foo
```

To:

```
from .mytool import foo
```

The dot in the module name is used for relative module import ([Ref Link Here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references)).